# Declaring income when self-employed

Tags: income-tax, self-employment, australia, sole-proprietorship

As described [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/108043/do-i-need-an-abn-for-self-employment), I earn extra money (around $7000 per year) from a second job, in which I am running a business as a sole trader. Due to the nature of the work, I am mostly paid in cash, and deposit the cash in the bank once every couple of weeks. When I do my tax return, how do I declare this extra income? Is it sufficient to provide my bank statements showing the money that I have deposited, or is there anything else required?

Comment: Presumably there's some Form where you enter Income, and Expenses, subtract the two and then add to the main form.  Also, this might help: https://rounded.com.au/blog/tax-for-sole-traders/

Comment: Regarding separate accounts (as touched on in [anonymous's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/109796/35567)), some/many banks will not like you "doing business" through a personal account and  may insist you open a separate business account. See [this question and its answers](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/75054/35567) (disclaimer: one of the answers is mine).

Comment: @TripeHound are the bank fees on business accounts tax deductible?

Comment: @1123581321 Sorry, no idea.

Comment: I hope you're making quarterly estimated payments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tax return has a section for completing business income. Reporting sole-trader income is very straightforward and easy to complete using MyTax online. As a sole-trader your business income is simply part of your normal personal tax return.

https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Tax-return/2018/Supplementary-tax-return/Income-questions-13-24/15-Net-income-or-loss-from-business-2018/

You don't need to provide any supporting documents when completing the return, but may be required to show evidence if you're audited in the future. I use separate personal and business bank accounts to make it easier to document income and expenses, but for a sole-trader it's not necessary.